# How do I add a hash to URL in meteor iron-router?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a Meteor app using [iron-router](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router) which displays rosters in tabs ([example here](https://signup.zone/demo/class)).  I would like the URL to include a hash that depends on which tab is showing, ie. http://example.com/myrosters#first.

I have event code like:

```
Template.roster.events({
'mousedown .nav-tabs li a': function (evt) { 
        # want to set the URL here
    }
});
```

How do I set the URL here to include a hash, without actually triggering an unnecessary page reload? (I believe `Router.go()` would trigger a page reload.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If the path stays the same then it seems `go` doesn't reload the page.

```
Router.go(window.location.pathname+"#test3")
```

When I execute the above, I see no activity in the network tab of the developers console, so I think this should work for your purposes.

Comment: Thanks. That looks promising, and it doesn't do a reload, but I find that in my case it doesn't add `#test3` to the end of the URL either - sometimes `#test3` does flash up there briefly, only to disappear again.  As a test, if I replace the command with `Router.go(another_page)` it directs me to another page just fine. Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: I also tried `window.location.hash = "test3";`, and see the same result - `#test3` flashes briefly at the end of the URL sometimes, but does not stay there.

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior you describe. On my system it stays there just fine (linux + chrome). Which browser and OS are you using?

Comment: That's interesting. I'm using Mac OS X and Firefox. I tried one of Safari and Chrome too and saw the same thing (sorry - can't remember which now).

Comment: what happens when you go to http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/iron-router-tutorial and do `Router.go(window.location.href + "#test");`?

Comment: That works! The address changes to `http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/iron-router-tutorial#test`. So I guess I must be doing something odd on my site. I am using `Router.configure({layoutTemplate: 'layout', notFoundTemplate: 'notfound'});` and then `Router.map(function () {this.route('roster', {path: '/:roster_id', template: 'roster', onAfterAction: function () { Session.set('roster_id', this.params.roster_id); } } });` . And then a `Deps.autorun(function () { ... })` that depends on this `Session` variable to load the roster from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **Router.go** You Can Use **Router.url**:

Router.url('yourrouterpathname', {_id: id}, {query: 'q=s', hash: 'hashFrag'});